# Sencha-Touch + PhoneGap application web-view reload issue

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I am developing a Sencha-Touch + PhoneGap application for Android and I am facing an issue that the web-view gets reloaded if the app was minimized for a long time.
The same thing happened when we run any memory cleaner apps on the device(Like Android Assistant,Clean Master etc..)

There is a login functionality in my app.So if the memory is cleared, the user needs to re-login to the app and the data inside the app will also be lost.(Please note that the data is very important)

How to prevent reload on android web-view when the app comes to foreground?
Or please suggest an alternative solution for retaining the user data.

Please note that I am using cordova 2.3 and sencha touch 2.3

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a client side data storage solution. Sencha Touch offer two solutions that may help you with this issue.

1. localstorage - http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

Specify a proxy on your store to use local storage

```
proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : 'important-data'
    }
```

1. sql storage - http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Sql

Specify a proxy on your store.

```
    proxy: {
      type: "sql"
   }
```

With either of the above solutions your data will be available client side independent of the webview being reloaded.